# How can I execute SSIS packages for SQL Server 2012 using VS 2015 .NET component?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2015

I'm able to execute packages through SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2015 against a SQL Server 2012 instance but when I use `Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDts` to execute a package in .NET code, I get:

> "The version number in the package is not valid. The version number cannot be greater than current version number."

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23014500/ssis-error-the-version-number-in-the-package-is-not-valid#answer-23536571) suggests to "rebuild the project in the correct version of BIDS that matches the server agent used to run the job" but I'm not sure how to do that.  I tried opening the project in SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2012 which did not work and I also tried using the `Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDts` assembly in the SQL Server 2012 SDK\Assemblies folder.

It would seem to me that if I can execute packages through Visual Studio 2015 for SQL Server 2012, I should be able to do the same through code.

### Solution

I added the `Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDts` assembly located in *C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS\v4.0_13.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91* as per Bruce's comment below and the package now executes successfully from .NET code.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I'm currently assuming it's something along the lines of what you already tried with where the ManagedDts assembly is located. I would suggest creating a dataflow script task, which should automatically reference similar assemblies, and see what location it uses for those references.

Comment: Thanks, I found a working version in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS\v4.0_13.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91.